# Importing customers with their hashed passwords from Oxid

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, import, password

We are running Magento 1.9.3.2 and need to import >100k customers from oxid.

Here is how Oxid generates the passwords:

```
public function encodePassword( $sPassword, $sSalt )
{
    $oDb = oxDb::getDb();
    return $oDb->getOne( "select MD5( CONCAT( ".$oDb->quote( $sPassword ).", UNHEX( '{$sSalt}' ) ) )" );
}
```

Here is how Magento 1.9.3.2 does that:

```
public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
{
    if (is_integer($salt)) {
        $salt = $this->_helper->getRandomString($salt);
    }
    return $salt === false ? $this->hash($password) : $this->hash($salt . $password) . ':' . $salt;
}
```

So I have naturally tried to do it this way:

1.) Tool a salt that was saved in oxid DB and then run it through SQL HEX()
2.) Saved the Oxid password with the new salt (after HEX()) in Magento database like this: Oxid_pass:new_salt
3.) Overwrote Magento getHash method to this (swaped $salt and $password place):

```
public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
{
    if (is_integer($salt)) {
        $salt = $this->_helper->getRandomString($salt);
    }
    return $salt === false ? $this->hash($password) : $this->hash($password . $salt) . ':' . $salt;
}
```

However, this change still does not allow me to login using password from Oxid.

The question is: what is the best practice if any to move users with password from Oxid to Magento?

Comment: Oxid apparently stores salt somewhere else, either in separate column or inside code, can you check this?

Comment: I have the salt, it is in the DB (mentioned in the 1st step).  I have actually identified the problem: I could not login because the Magento validateHash function was still using old PASSWORD+SALT combination. Once I have changed it to SALT+PASSWORD it now works. If no other answers about the best practice appears in the next few days, I will answer my own question fur future readers.